# docker: first command not working - error during connect

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop, windows-11

```
> docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
docker: error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

From windows 11 services:

```
Docker desktop service is running.
```

Is it the daemon? Restarting the service did not help.

Can this be related to WSL?

```
> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

How to start them without re-installation? Could not find WSL command for this.

> docker info

```
docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.10.3)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.15.1)
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc., v0.1.0)
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc., v0.2.18)
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc., 0.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.25.0)
  scout: Command line tool for Docker Scout (Docker Inc., v0.6.0)

Server:
ERROR: error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/info": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```